# Create index to speedup join on (1) ids match and (2) dates within a range

Tags: sql, postgresql

What index should I create for Table B to optimize a join on (1) ids matching and (2) date falls within some range.

Update: the issue is I have hundreds of thousands of dates but only 25 portfolios... condition (2) does all the work in cutting down the size of the resulting join...

More specifically, imagine I have a Table A:

```
portfolio id    |   begin_date   |   end_date  
---------------------------------------------
      1         |    20150101    |   20150130
etc...
```

and a Table B:

```
portfolio_id    |     date       |    daily_ret
-----------------------------------------------
      1              20150102            .00001
      1              20150103           -.01023
etc...
```

The query I would like to not totally suck is:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b on (a.portfolio_id = b.portfolio_id) and
                      (a.begin_date < b.date) and
                      (b.date <= a.end_date)
```

I think I want some kinda index like:
`CREATE INDEX tableb_idx ON tableb (portfolio_id, date)`

But I'm a total n00b with SQL indexes... I imagine there's an issue with the `(a.begin_date < b.date) and (b.date <= a.end_date)` part?

---

Update with more specific info:

```
   Column   |       Type       | Modifiers 
------------+------------------+-----------
 yyyymmdd   | integer          | not null
 size_index | integer          | not null
 beme_index | integer          | not null
 ret        | double precision | 
Indexes:
    "portfolio_25_size_beme_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (yyyymmdd, size_index, beme_index)
```

Exact query:

```
explain analyze
SELECT exp(sum(log(1 + f_sbm.ret))) - 1 as size_beme_ret, count(*) T,
        permno, period_start, period_end
FROM eb2.deleteme x
JOIN fama_french.portfolio_25_size_beme f_sbm
ON f_sbm.size_index = x.me_idx5 AND f_sbm.beme_index = x.beme_idx5 AND x.ps < f_sbm.yyyymmdd and f_sbm.yyyymmdd <= x.pe
GROUP BY permno, period_start, period_end
```

Results (note I limited eb2.deleteme to 1000 rows because all 180000 wouldn't finish...)

```
HashAggregate  (cost=83599.59..83602.59 rows=200 width=24) (actual time=11209.030..11209.455 rows=949 loops=1)
  Group Key: x.permno, x.period_start, x.period_end
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=78736.24..83566.19 rows=1909 width=24) (actual time=1183.677..11184.172 rows=19492 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: ((f_sbm.size_index = x.me_idx5) AND (f_sbm.beme_index = x.beme_idx5))
        Join Filter: ((x.ps < f_sbm.yyyymmdd) AND (f_sbm.yyyymmdd <= x.pe))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 22659494
        ->  Sort  (cost=78655.60..80136.72 rows=592450 width=20) (actual time=1182.834..1647.155 rows=545055 loops=1)
              Sort Key: f_sbm.size_index, f_sbm.beme_index
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 17328kB
              ->  Seq Scan on portfolio_25_size_beme f_sbm  (cost=0.00..9698.50 rows=592450 width=20) (actual time=0.014..155.770 rows=592450 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=80.64..83.54 rows=1160 width=32) (actual time=0.797..1618.708 rows=22678987 loops=1)
              Sort Key: x.me_idx5, x.beme_idx5
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 102kB
              ->  Seq Scan on deleteme x  (cost=0.00..21.60 rows=1160 width=32) (actual time=0.020..0.357 rows=1000 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.574 ms
Execution time: 11228.745 ms
```

---

Maybe this is a hack, but forcing the join on DATE first then pruning the portfolio mismatches later runs 11x faster...

```
with stage1 as(
SELECT *
FROM eb2.deleteme x
JOIN fama_french.portfolio_25_size_beme f_sbm
ON x.ps < f_sbm.yyyymmdd and f_sbm.yyyymmdd <= x.pe
)
select exp(sum(log(1+ret))) - 1 as size_beme_ret, count(*) T,
        permno, period_start, period_end
FROM stage1 f_sbm
WHERE size_index = me_idx5 and beme_index = beme_idx5
GROUP BY permno, period_start, period_end
```

Comment: You might need an index on both tables. I don't see anything wrong with your query. How many rows in the tables and how long does this take to run? Is Portfolio_id a primary key in tableA?

Comment: The information you provide is not enough to understand what is the issue or offer any advice. Can you include the whole of the explain analyze instead of just a section (including the execution time and cost) along with the DDL of the tables involved? (at least all of the columns involved JOINs and WHERE clauses)

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister Thanks, for taking a look. I just updated the question...

Comment: After some debugging, I think the issue is that: (1) I have a bajillion dates but (2) only 25 portfolios. What really does all the pruning is the inequality constraints, NOT the equality constraint.

Comment: Seems to be solved. Postgresql was also INSISTING on doing a merge_join instead of a nested loop even though a nested loop turns out to be insanely, insanely faster. fixed it temporarily at least with: `set enable_mergejoin=false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always create indexes that are intended to being compared through equality *first*, and through greater/lower than (or between) *last* (and just that final one, since including any further columns will generally not assist with any query of this nature).

Adding the following index will speed-up your query considerably:

```
CREATE INDEX ON fama_french.portfolio_25_size_beme (size_index, beme_index, yyyymmdd);
```